# How to prevent evaluation of string in make / shell?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have this makefile:

```
echo:
    echo "PASS=$(PASS)"
```

Which I invoke:

```
PASS='MYPA$$' make
```

Which shows me:

```
echo "PASS=MYPA$"
PASS=MYPA$
```

Somebody is evaluating `$$` -> `$`.

Is this the shell? Not when inputting the value, since I use single-quotes, preventing the shell to evaluate it.

Maybe the shell invoked by make is doing this ...

Or is it maybe `make` itself?

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Make is doing the interpolation.  `$` is a special character in make, and is escaped by `$`, so that `$FOO` becomes the value of the variable FOO while `$$FOO` becomes the literal string `$FOO`

Comment: You can't avoid it.  What are you trying to accomplish?  If you want to echo the string `MYPA$$`, write `echo MYPA$$$$` in the makefile.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The variable `PASS` is not only used by make, it will be used by other tools (python scripts for example). It does not make sense to set a value which can only be consumed by make. There must be a way of telling make: _do not do any interpolation of this variable_

Comment: Are you trying to assign the literal string `MYPA$$` to the variable PASS?  If so, just do `PASS = MYPA$$$$`

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, that is what i am trying to do. The variable is coming via the environment, and is going to be used by a makefile and by other tools. If I set it to `MYPA$$$$` (which is a lie, just to overcome make's limitations), I break the other tools. According to your suggestion I need to set a `PASS_FOR_MAKE=MYPA$$$$` and `PASS_FOR_OTHER_TOOLS=MYPA$$`, which is not nice.

Comment: Even if I manage to generate a double-$$ variable contents, the bash that I use keeps replacing the double-$$ with some numbers in the echo command: `echo "PASS='MYPA$$'"`  `PASS='MYPA10096'` so rather than blaming make for a deficiency you should rethink the use of $$ in a shellscript context in the first place.

Comment: @Vroomfondel use single quotes in the shell. The password I am dealing with has a double dollar, nothing I can rethink about it. That's a business requirement, and something that make should be able to support. Or, stating this more clearly: a password can have (nearly) any unicode character, and this should not cause trouble in makefiles and/or scripts, when properly handled.

Comment: @DanielGonzalez What you are trying to accomplish is highly unnatural (and error prone). Each scripting language (let us consider make syntax as a kind of scripting language) has its own set of special characters that get interpreted if not escaped, and its own way to escape characters. Expecting that several scripting languages will have compatible such sets and escape rules is a bit optimistic. The best you can do, I am afraid, is encoding - decoding with a code that avoids all special characters.

Comment: @WilliamPursell *so that $FOO becomes the value of the variable FOO*: no, `$FOO` becomes the value of the variable `F`, followed by `OO`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet and each scripting language has a method of treating strings as **pure strings**, _without applying special interpolation rules_. It may not be natural to do it, since each tool has a special purpose, but usually can be achieved with some workaround. Also in make (see answer by @randomir)

Comment: As make doesn't really have datatypes and therefore has no need to delimit strings, it is an exception to your "each scripting language" rule. randomirs trick is to use the shell and will work only if PASS is a shell variable. Assigning with `:=` does not save you from the $-eating gremlin in make.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### On `make` variables

It's better to think of `make` variables as **macros**, than as conventional variables (actually in some versions of `make`, variables are called macros). The reason is, each time a variable is referenced, [it is expanded](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC57).

An example from the docs illustrates the standard [*recursively expanded variables*](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC59) behaviour:

```
foo = $(bar)
bar = $(ugh)
ugh = Huh?

all:
    echo $(foo)

# echoes: Huh?
# `$(foo)' expands to `$(bar)' which expands to `$(ugh)' which finally expands to `Huh?'
```

If you are using GNU `make`, one way to avoid further expansion is by using the [*simply expanded variables*](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC59):

> **Simply expanded variables** are defined by lines using `:=` (see section Setting Variables). The value of a simply expanded variable is **scanned once and for all, expanding any references to other variables and functions, when the variable is defined**. The actual value of the simply expanded variable is the result of expanding the text that you write. It does not contain any references to other variables; it contains their values as of the time this variable was defined.

Although simply expanded variables behave more like variables in most programming languages, their sole usage wouldn't solve the problem of environment variables' expansion here because even the first reference `var := $(PASS)` would expand `$$` from the `PASS` environment variable.

#### Avoiding expansion of environment variables

We can use the [`shell`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_8.html#SEC83) function in `make` to read our environment variable in shell (and not expand it in `make`):

```
expanded := $(shell echo "$$PASS")

test:
    echo 'PASS=$(expanded)'
    echo "PASS=$$PASS"
```

The `shell` function will execute `echo "$PASS"` in shell (`$$` is expanded to `$` by `make`  when function is executed), and the result (the value of your shell variable `PASS`) will be stored in the `make` variable `expanded`. This variable can now be freely used elsewhere in `make`, without ever being further expanded.

The only processing `make` does on the result, before substituting it into the surrounding text, is to convert each newline or carriage-return / newline pair to a single space. It also removes the trailing (carriage-return and) newline, if it's the last thing in the result.

The example above illustrates how to use the `make` variable **`expanded`** and the environment variable **`PASS`** in your `Makefile` script:

```
$ PASS='MYPA$$' make
echo 'PASS=MYPA$$'
PASS=MYPA$$
echo "PASS=$PASS"
PASS=MYPA$$
```

Comment: This will work just as well with the expanding assignment `=`.

Comment: @Vroomfondel, you're right. I've updated the answer to better emphasize the significance of `shell`. Thanks!